# Why MarshalByRefObject.GetLifetimeService method is final virtual

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8, .net-remoting

Accidentally I found out that `MarshalByRefObject.GetLifetimeService method` on **.NET Framework** is `final virtual`.

```
> typeof(MarshalByRefObject).GetMethod("GetLifetimeService").Attributes
PrivateScope, Public, Final, Virtual, HideBySig, VtableLayoutMask
```

I saw [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/marshalbyrefobject.cs) of this class and method looks like normal instance non virtual method:

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
public Object GetLifetimeService()
{
    return LifetimeServices.GetLease(this); 
}
```

But than I saw it IL disassembler code:

```
.method public final hidebysig newslot virtual 
    instance object GetLifetimeService () cil managed 
{
    // method body
}
```

It is *virtual* but *final* (`sealed` in C#) method that doesn't make sense in my opinion.

Than I checked that strange thing on **.NET [Core]** and method is not virtual here:

```
> typeof(MarshalByRefObject).GetMethod("GetLifetimeService").Attributes
PrivateScope, Public, HideBySig
```

Now I am very interested and want to find out why this happened and how it is possible.

Comment: `MarshalByRefObject` probably has a lot of runtime hooks into it.

Comment: @DanielA.White, what you mean?

Comment: in .net core `MarshalByRefObject` is a dead object btw